# SQLAlchemy: How do I access a relationship in two Tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a system to keep track of current device firmware and compare this with a recommended version. Models and code has been simplified below. I have three models: `Version`, `FirmwareHistory` and `VersionRecommendation`.

- `Version` has the attributes `major`, `minor`, `patch`, and `bugfix`;
- `FirmwareHistory` has `date_changed`, `version`, and `device`;
- `VersionRecommendation` has `date`, `version`, `user_who_changed`, and `preferred`.

The `VersionRecommendation` table can list multiple `Versions` as preferred because we support multiple major branches. Now I'm trying to cross reference the `FirmwareHistory` and `VersionRecommendation` to see if the device is running a recommended version or higher.

The following query gives me a list of all the devices running a recommended version.

```
session.query(FirmwareHistory, func.max(FirmwareHistory.date), VersionRecommendation)\
            .filter(VersionRecommendation.preferred == True)\
            .group_by(FirmwareHistory.device_id)\
            .filter(FirmwareHistory.version_id == VersionRecommendation.version_id)
            .all()
```

However I would also like to access the `Version` attribute of `FirmwareHistory` and `VersionRecommendation` to check the `major` attribute. and only return the results where the version `major` is the same.

Basically:
Give me a result where the `FirmwareHistory` and `VersionRecommendation` both have the same `Version.major`

I've tried:

```
session().query(FirmwareHistory, func.max(FirmwareHistory.date), VersionRecommendation)\
    .filter(VersionRecommendation.preferred == True)\
    .group_by(FirmwareHistory.device_id)\
    .filter(VersionRecommendation.version.major == FirmwareHistory.version.major)\
    .all()
```

But that gives me a Attribute error:
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with SoftwareRevision.version has an attribute 'major'

I've tried joining both versions in but SQLAlchemy gets confused because of column names:

```
session.query(FirmwareHistory, func.max(FirmwareHistory.date), VersionRecommendation)\
    .filter(VersionRecommendation.preferred == True)\
    .group_by(FirmwareHistory.device_id)\
    .join(FirmwareHistory.version)\
    .join(VersionRecommendation.version)\
    .filter(FirmwareHistory.version_id == VersionRecommendation.version_id)
    .all()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reference version through `FirmwareHistory` or `VersionRecommendation`, but just access it as a model:

```py
session.query(FirmwareHistory, func.max(FirmwareHistory.date), VersionRecommendation)\
    .select_from(FirmwareHistory)\
    .join(Version)\
    .join(VersionRecommendation)\
    .filter(VersionRecommendation.preferred == True)\
    .group_by(FirmwareHistory.device_id)\
    .all()
```

or, if you really want to avoid the extra join, you can specify the join condition explicitly. I wouldn't do this, though, because very often PostgreSQL is smart enough to just optimise that away.

```py
session.query(FirmwareHistory, func.max(FirmwareHistory.date), VersionRecommendation)\
    .select_from(FirmwareHistory)\
    .join(VersionRecommendation, FirmwareHistory.version_id == VersionRecommendation.version_id)\
    .filter(VersionRecommendation.preferred == True)\
    .group_by(FirmwareHistory.device_id)\
    .all()
```

Comment: And how will i compare the major column of both FirmwareHistory and VersionRecommendation?

Comment: For that I need some more context. You current query wouldn't execute because `MAX(DATE)` requires all non-grouped elements in the GROUP BY clause. Do you want that as a column or do you just want the last entry of the `FirmwareHistory`? Do you want _all_ `VersionRecommendation`s matching the major version of the `FirmwareHistory` or just one? Let's continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218963/discussion-about-sqlalchemy-how-do-i-access-a-relationship-in-two-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Alright!
Got it work using aliased 'Versions'

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
...
firmware_version = aliased(Version)
recommended_version = aliased(Version)

session().query(FirmwareHistory, func.max(FirmwareHistory.date), VersionRecommendation)\
            .filter(VersionRecommendation.preferred == True)\
            .group_by(FirmwareHistory.device_id)\
            .join(firmware_version, FirmwareHistory.version_id==firmware_version.id)\
            .join(recommended_version, VersionRecommendation.version_id==recommended_version.id)\
            .filter(recommended_version.major == firmware_version.major)\
            .all()
```

With this i get the current version with the recommended version that runs the same major.